# Как правильно: булевы значения или булевы состояния?

Tags: терминология, булева-алгебра, русификация

Пишу стайл гид по одному скриптовому язычку. И в нем, помимо прочих, такие главы:

```
вариант 1
* Сравнение с булевыми значениями
* Возврат булевых значений
```

Насколько это грамотно, как с точки зрения программирования, так и с точки зрения русского языка?

Другие варианты, которые я рассматривал:

```
вариант 2
* Проверка булевых значений
* Возврат булевых значений
```

```
вариант 3
* Проверка булевых состояний
* Возврат булевых состояний
```

А вот то, что в них содержится (не судите строго за наивность написанного, это просто чтоб было понятней о чем речь):

```
Сравнение с булевыми значениями
  правильно: If (Var)
неправильно: If (Var == True)
```

```
Возврат булевых значений
  правильно: Return True
неправильно: Return 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном контексте - **"значения"**.
Состояния имеют системы, а переменные и константы - имеют значения.